# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>

Tags: c#

my problem is occurred when I tried to grouping data from two tables in this controller as below:

```
public class QuestionModelsController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public ActionResult Quiz()
    {
        var Ans = from ansewrs in db.AnswerModels
                 join question in db.QuestionModels
                 on  ansewrs.QuestionID equals question.ID

                 select ansewrs;
        var grouped = from j in Ans
                      group j by j.Question.QuestionText
                      into gr
                      select new CheckListModel
                      {
                          QuestionText = gr.Key,
                          Questions = gr

                      };
        return View(grouped.ToList());
    }
```

My ViewModels are:

```
public class CheckListModel
{
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<QuestionModel> Questions { get; set;  }

}

public class QuestionModel
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string QuestionText { set; get; }
    public string SelectedAnswer { set; get; }
    public virtual IList<AnswerModel> Answers { set; get; }


}
public class AnswerModel
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string AnswerText { set; get; }

    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionModel Question { get; set; }

}
```

This row `Questions = gr` is not recognized , thus this error will occur:
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Linq.IGrouping<string, MyAssembly.AnswerModel>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyAssembly.QuestionModel>'`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Please help me and Thank you very much

Comment: You can try to use `Questions = gr.ToList()`, but you have a different type of source and destination collections, `AnswerModel` and `QuestionModel`. It makes sense to review the logic of your queries

Comment: Try `Questions = gr.Select(a => a.Question)`

Comment: As an aside, it looks as though your `CheckListModel` is just a grouping of `QuestionModels` by `QuestionText`. You could probably simplify the whole query by completely removing the join with the `AnswerModels`

Comment: Thanks very much Pavel Anikhouski and devNull for your help , I found the error is here: just I replace  "public virtual IEnumerable<QuestionModel> Questions { get; set;  }" by public virtual IEnumerable<AnswerModel>Questions { get; set;  }

Answer (score 1):

"Questions" is typed as being a sequence of questions. You are giving it a sequence of groups of answers. The problem here isn't with the code; rather, the compiler is doing its job to explain that there is something *conceptually* wrong with what you are doing. You've made some error where you've confused "sequence of questions" with "groups of answers"; resolve that discrepancy and rewrite the code appropriately.

Comment: Yes sir , my request "Questions" is typed as being a sequence of questions. and I'm giving it a sequence of groups of answers. How can I resolve that discrepancy and rewrite the code appropriately. Please help me sir and thank you very much

Comment: Thank you sir Eric Lippert very much for your help , error was here: just I replace "public virtual IEnumerable<QuestionModel> Questions { get; set; }" by public virtual IEnumerable<AnswerModel>Questions { get; set; } , 
the problem solved